# Product with positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some trouble proving this:

Let $A^T = A$ be positive definite. For all $v$:s such that $v^TAv \leq 1$ it also holds that $(Bv)^TA(Bv) = v^TB^TABv \leq 1$. Then it holds that $A-B^TAB$ must be at least positive semi-definite (could also be positive definite).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists $v$ such that
$$
v^T(A - B^TAB)v < 0
$$
Because $v^TAv > 0$, let
$$
u = \sqrt{\frac{1}{v^TAv}}\cdot v
$$
We have
$$
u^T(A - B^TAB)u = \frac{1}{v^TAv}\cdot v^T(A-B^TAB)v < 0 \tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$
However, because $u^TAu = \frac{1}{v^TAv} \cdot v^TAv = 1$, we further have
$$
u^TB^TABu \leq 1
$$
thus
$$
u^T(A - B^TAB)u \geq 0 \tag{$\spadesuit$}
$$
A contradiction with $(\clubsuit)$. We therefore conclude that $A - B^TAB$ is positive semi-definite.